# Why doesn't plotly show the date properly on hover?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

[image: Data with the date variable]i'm creating a dashboard using the shiny package. One of the plots, which is supposed to show the date on hover is not doing so, instead, its displaying a decimal value for the date. 
Date is saved in the as.Date() function, in the 'date' variable :

```
custData$date <- as.Date(custData$date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Server.R code for displaying the plot:

```
output$sidePlot2 <- renderPlotly({print(ggplotly(custData %>%
       group_by(date) %>% summarise(revenue = sum(lineTotal)) %>%
            ggplot(aes(x = date, y = revenue)) + geom_line() + geom_smooth(method =                  'auto', se = FALSE) + labs(x = 'Date', y = 'Revenue (£)', title =                       'Overall Revenue Trend by Date')
            )
       )
   }
)
```

[image: Plot with wrong date format on hover]

Comment: May be the date conversion is not right, can you share reproduce your data?

Comment: Try downloading the newest version of `ggplot2` with `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")`. I recently came across a similar issue and resolved it by upgrading from `2.2.1` (the CRAN version) to `2.2.1.9000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to define `text` inside `aes` of `ggplot`.

```r
... %>% ggplot(aes(x = date, y = revenue,
           text = paste('Date: ', as.Date(date),
                        '<br>Revenue: ', revenue))) + 
  geom_line() + 
  ...
```